# Partial Derivatives of $F(x,y,z)$ where $z = f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

When finding the tangent plane of a surface, given by $z = f(x,y)$, one method for doing so is writing $z$ implicitly: $F(x,y,z) = z - f(x,y) = 0.$

It is well established that the tangent plane of $F(x,y,z) = 0$ at $P(a,b,c)$, in general, is

(1) $$F_x(a,b,c)(x-a) + F_y(a,b,c)(y-b) + F_z(a,b,c)(z-c) = 0.$$

However, the corollary of this theorem is that if $z = f(x,y)$, then the tangent plane is given by

(2) $$-f_x(a,b)(x-a) + -f_y(a,b)(y-b) + (z-c) = 0.$$

> What I do not understand is why this follows from the (1).

In particular, let's examine $F_x(a,b,c). F_x(a,b,c) = F_x(z - f(x,y))$. I am confused why $F_x(z) = 0$. I thought $z = f(x,y)$, so shouldn't $F_x(z) = F_x(f) = f_x(a,b)$? Why can we treat $z$ as a constant here if it is a function of $x$ (and $y$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are "confused why $F_x(z) = 0$", then conclude with "shouldn't $F_x(z) = F_x(f) = f_x(a,b)$?" But in fact, in going from your equation (1) to equation (2), the exact replacement $F_x(a,b,c) = f_x(a,b)$ (actually, its negative, due to the particular definition of $F$) is made that you seem to be suggesting.  This I find confusing.

You go on to ask "Why can we treat $z$ as a constant here if it is a function of $x$ (and $y$)?"  But $z$ is *not* a function of $x$ and $y$. The *function* depending on $x$ and $y$ is $\,f$ (which we are not given here in terms of $x$ and $y$), while $z = f(x,y)$ is simply its *value* at $(x,y)$. Along the same lines, the notation $F_x$ usually stands for the *function*  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$, so that $F_x(a,b,c) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(a,b,c)$. In that sense, your conjectures involving $F_x(z)$ and $F_x(f)$ make no sense, since the domain of $F$ and its partial derivatives is some subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

There are two functions involved here, and $z$ is not one of them. You have $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = r$, some real number, and $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ with $F(x,y,z) = z-f(x,y)$, subject to the level surface condition $F(x,y,z) = 0$. The function $f$ has two partial derivatives, $f_x$ and $f_y$, while $F$ has three partial derivatives, related to those of $f$ by $F_x = -f_x$, $F_y = -f_y$, and $F_z = 1$. Your equation (2) follows from equation (1) by making these replacements (or rather, their negatives) at the point $P = (a,b,c)$ where $(a,b)$ is in the domain of $f$, and $(a,b,c)$ is in the domain of $F$.

I hope this is helpful to you.

**ADDENDUM**

It is clear by now that my answer has *not* been helpful, and in fact seems to have generated more confusion, as witnessed by the comments. I should have been more clear from the outset, I suppose, that I don't understand how to interpret your notations "$F_x(z)$" and "$F_x(f)$".

You understand that $z = f(x,y)$ defines a *surface*, where $z$ is a *dependent* variable which varies with $x$ and $y$ via the function $f$. This is also the *level surface* $F(x,y,z) = 0$ of the function $F$ of three *independent* variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ defined by $F(x,y,z) = z - f(x,y)$. You seem to want to restrict the independent variable $z$ in the definition of $F$ to satisfy $z = f(x,y)$, which is true only on the level surface $F(x,y,z) = 0$, i.e., $F(x,y,f(x,y)) = f(x,y)-f(x,y) = 0$. But in determining the equation of the tangent plane to $F$ at one of its points, say $(a,b,c)$, we do not restrict $F$ to a *particular* level surface in taking its gradient. The *independent* variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ are allowed to vary *freely* over the domain of $F$, which yield the usual partial derivatives and results mentioned in the last paragraph of my earlier answer (and in other answers to the question).

Comment: "But $z$ is *not* a function of $x$ and $y$" I think this is not correct. If $z=f(x,y)=x+y$ then for different values of $x$ and $y$ we have different values of $z$. So $z$ depends on $x$ and $y$, hence $z$ is function of $x$ and $y$. In other words, $z=f(x,y)$.

Comment: @manooooh, I was trying to be careful here, maybe a bit too careful. But I would say instead that if $f(x,y) = x+y$, then for different values of $x$ and $y$ we have different values of $f$. Of course, I understand that it is common practice to call out these values by another name, such as $z$. But I don't think of these function _values_ as the function itself. To me, broadly speaking, the function is the set of rules by which its value is determined from $x$ and $y$. Perhaps this is too nit-picky, or even downright wrong. If so, I am sure the community will let me know in further comments.

Comment: Yeah, we have to be careful with this kind of notation. For example, we do not write $x^2+y^2+f^2(x,y)=1$ but $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ to graph an sphere. Anyway, I think the "$z=f(x,y)$" means exactly "$z$ depends on $x$ and $y$". But you are right, we can wait further comments.

Comment: @splitcomplexes thank you for your addendum. I think it makes more sense now. So, to clarify/confirm my understanding, When we define a function F of 3 variables, x, y, and z, this z has nothing to do with "z = f(x,y)". However, when we examine the level curve at 0 of F, it does; at this level curve, 0, z = f(x,y).

Comment: @Typical Highschooler, I'm glad the addendum helped, and yes, I think you have it. $F$ is a function defined for _arbitrary_ $x$, $y$, and $z$ (in its domain) by $F(x,y,z) = z - f(x,y)$. This function defines a particular _level_ surface (not _curve_) by the condition $F(x,y,z) = 0$ (not  _at_ $0$), which _is_ the surface defined by $z = f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated. With $F(x,y,z):=f(x,y)-z$,

$$\begin{align}
F_x(x,y,z)&=f_x(x,y),
\\F_y(x,y,z)&=f_y(x,y),
\\F_z(x,y,z)&=-1.\end{align}$$

Partial derivatives assume that only one variable is active, the others are seen as constants.

---

**Addendum:**

If you consider that the functional relation between $z$ and $f(x,y)$ holds while taking the partials, you arrive at an absurdity: if $z=f(x,y)$,

$$F(x,y,z)=0$$

and

$$F_x(x,y,z)=F_y(x,y,z)=F_z(x,y,z)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then level surface $F^{-1}(0) =\{
(x,y,f(x,y))\}$ has a normal vector : $$ {\rm grad}\ F = (-
f_x,-f_y, 1) $$

Hence at a point $P(a,b,c)$, $$ {\rm grad}\ F(P)\cdot
\bigg((x,y,z)-P\bigg) =0 $$