# How do I calculate the z-partial derivative of $f(x, y, z)$ where $z=x+y$?

Tags: partial-derivative, substitution

Despite my question has a title similar to [Partial Derivatives of $F(x,y,z)$ where $z = f(x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965544/partial-derivatives-of-fx-y-z-where-z-fx-y) I didn't understand its solution. I'm sorry for my ignorance on this subject.

How do I calculate the z-partial derivative of $f(x, y, z)$ where z=x+y? Or in a general form, where $z=g(x, y)$? I'm asking because I don't know how to deal with, using a wrong notation for example, $\frac{\partial f(x, y) } {\partial (x+y)} $.

Comment: Where did you see $\partial f /\partial (-x-y)$?

Comment: Thomas, I modified the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But you did not answer the question ;-) - where did you encounter that notation? It does not make sense to me.

Comment: Thomas, this notation does not make sense to me too. I used because it is the only one that I know in my ignorance.

Comment: What you'll need to clarify (for yourself, and for us) is what exactly you would like to compute, and why. What is the function, what does it depend on, which quantity is varying as you take the derivative, and what quantities are being held constant? As it stands, this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative notation is indicating differentiation with respect to a certain argument of a function depending on several variables - it does not take into account whether that argument has further dependencies. So if you have $$f(x,y,z) = z$$ then $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (x, y, g(x,y, t, \alpha))= 1 \text{ and }
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y, g(x,y, t, \alpha))= 0$$
regardless of what $g$ is.

As another example, if you look at $h(x,y, z) = z^2$ then

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = 2z  $$ and, consequently,
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} (a, b, g(x,y)) = 2g(x,y) $$

If you want to differentiate, say, $f(x,y,x^2+y)$ and want to indicate you are interested in the dependency on $x$, you would write
$$\frac{df}{dx}$$
and the result would be (in the example given above), according to the chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{dz}{dx} = 0 + 0 + 2x $$

Comment: Thomas, if one has $f(x, y, z=x+y^2)$ and I want to calculate $f_{, z} $? Is there a general procedure for it? Because I can only see my ignorant way, that is to derivative in relation to z and substitute what I found by $z=x+y^2$.

Comment: What do you mean now by writing $f,z$? The partial derivative? Just take the definition of $f$, calculate the derivative w.r.t. to the $z$ variable and then, in the result, replace $z$ by $x+y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there isn't a general procedure for it. As Thomas said, the way it is to calculate the derivative to z and, in the result, replace z by $z=g(x, y)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Remark:** the notation $F_z(a,b,c)$ is a source of confusion.  There is no $z$ in the expression; its a 'dummy argument' for the "third argument of the expression"; and after taking the derivation the arguments $a,b,c$ are then substituted in.    So that would be  $$F_z(a,b,c)=\left.\dfrac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial z}\right\rvert_{(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)}$$

...  I'd suggest using $F_1,F_2, F_3$ or such to indicate differentiation with respect to an argument, rather than a dummy variable.

---

> using a wrong notation for example, $\frac{∂f(x,y)}{∂(x+y)}$

Yeap, so wrong.  Use $\left.\frac{\partial f(w)}{\partial w}\right\rvert_{w=x+y}$ as below.

This is just $f'(x+y)$: the dervative of $f$ evaluated at $x+y$. Which is $f_1(x+y)$ in the suggested notation.

---

From the start $$F_1(a,b,c)(x-a)+F_2(a,b,c)(y-b)+F_3(a,b,c)(z-c)=0\tag 1$$

When we take $F(x,y,z)=z-f(x+y)$, we can evaluate these terms:

$$\begin{align}F_1(a,b,c) &=\dfrac{\partial[ c-f(a+b)]}{\partial a}\\&= -\dfrac{\partial f(a+b)}{\partial a}\\[1ex] &= -\left.\dfrac{\partial f(w)}{\partial w}\right\rvert_{w=a+b}\cdot\dfrac{\partial [a+b]}{\partial a}\\[1ex]&=-f_1(a+b)\\[2ex] F_2(a,b,c)&= -f_1(a+b)\\[2ex] F_3(a,b,c) &=\dfrac{\partial [c-f(a+b)]}{\partial c}\\&=1  \end{align}$$

So we obtain from (1) $$-f_1(x+y)~(x-a)- f_1(x+y)~(y-b)+ (z-c)=0\tag{2'}$$

When $f(x+y)=x+y$, that becomes: $$-(x-a)- (y-b)+ (z-c)=0\tag{2''}$$